# Android Systrace tool internally uses strace or ftrace?

Tags: android, linux, trace, systrace

**Systrace** Android tool calls internally a tool called **atrace** which is and extension of **ftrace** or **strace** (Linux tools).

If we connect via the emulator console (ADB shell) to Android Jelly Bean we can execute **strace** tool but we **can not** execute **ftrace** tool (command not installed).

Doing some reseach over the Internet I found that **strace** is a predecessor of **ftrace**:
http://crtags.blogspot.de/2012/04/dtrace-ftrace-ltrace-strace-so-many-to.html

Looking to Android Source Code, the most "*internal*" reference that I found is **Trace.h** file:
http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/native/include/utils/Trace.h

I think that this file is then resolved to a native Linux driver.

However, I'm still unable to know if this implementation driver belongs to **strace** or **ftrace**. "Normally", it should be **ftrace** because it is newer, but in that case I don't know why we can not run **ftrace** from the emulator. In contrast, **strace** is completely available from the emulator.

Then, does someone knows if **Systrace** Android tool uses at a very low level **strace** or **ftrace**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've follow the instructions found here, related to **ftrace**,:
http://www.linuxforu.com/2010/11/kernel-tracing-with-ftrace-part-1/

Everything works perfect. I wasn't able to execute **ftrace** before because interacting and retrieving data is done via logical paths.

To execute **ftrace**, after correctly configuration (many steps...), inside adb shell:

```
root@android:# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace > mytracefile.txt
```

**atrace** makes configuration process easier, so we can access to trace information the following way:

```
root@android:# atrace -s -w -t 100 > mytracefile.txt
```

On the other hand, I've found information about executing **strace** here:
http://www.hokstad.com/5-simple-ways-to-troubleshoot-using-strace

All indicated examples were successfully executed in my environment using adb shell.

**Interaction and access to results of both tools are very different.**

Now I can say that **systrace** Android tool is based in **atrace** which in turn is based in **ftrace**.

**strace** is also supported but serves to another purposes and is not related to **systrace**.

Regards,