# atrace events: how to make them visible in systrace?

Tags: android, profiling, systrace

Good day everyone! 
I am pretty new to android profiling. And recently I have found, that systrace from google sdk call atrace. I also found that there is a set of functions from libcutils, which one could use for creating atrace events and in such a way profile, for example, c++ code.

I`ve found headers, made a dynamic loading with libcutils.so and after including everything build my lib and integrate it in apk. After it I install it on the phone and try to profile with systrace.py, but i could not find any call in systrace log to my created event.

I try to place Artace_begin(name)/Atrace_end() in different places, but still nothing changes.

So may be someone could help me, please, how to make it properly working and detect atrace event in systrace log?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001915/is-logging-android-systrace-events-directly-from-native-code-possible-without-j the answer can be found here, a very simple solution.

Comment: But keep in mind that it seems to work only with console apps. If you want to profile lib file, which connected to your apk, this variant seems to be not working for such cases